# Scrapy spider cralws only one link per page

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to scrape all the events data from `http://www.nyhistory.org/programs/upcoming-public-programs`. The events are paginated, 5 events per page. I created two rules: one to follow the next page and another one to follow events' details pages. So, I expect the spider first to enter each of the events' urls, to collect all the data I need from there and then to proceed to the next page, enter each of the events' urls and so on. However, for some reason my Spider accesses only one event from each of the pages, and that is the first event only. Please, see my code below

```
import scrapy
from nyhistory.items import EventItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from datetime import datetime
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re

class NyhistorySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "events"

    start_urls = ['http://www.nyhistory.org/programs/upcoming-public-programs',]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='.*?page=.*',restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="pager-next"]'), follow=True),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="view-content"]/div[contains(@class,"views-row")]'), callback='parse_event_details',follow=True),
            ]

    def parse_event_details(self, response):

        base_url = 'http://www.nyhistory.org'

        item = EventItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="views-field-title"]//text()')[2].extract()
        item['eventWebsite'] = response.url

        details_area = response.xpath('//div[@class="body-programs"]')
        details_area_str = " ".join(details_area.extract())
        details_area_str_split = re.split('EVENT DETAILS|LOCATION|PURCHASING TICKETS', details_area_str)
        speakers_names_area = details_area_str_split[1]
        speakersNames = Selector(text=speakers_names_area).xpath('strong').extract()
        try:
            item['speaker1FirstName'] = speakersNames[0].split()[0]
            item['speaker1LastName'] = speakersNames[0].split()[1]
        except:
            item['speaker1FirstName'] = ''
            item['speaker1LastName'] = ''

        description = remove_tags(details_area_str_split[1]).strip()
        item['description'] = description

        try:
            address_line = remove_tags(details_area_str_split[2]).strip()
            item['location'] = address_line.split(',')[0]
            item['city'] = address_line.split(',')[-2].strip()
            item['state'] = address_line.split(',')[-1].split()[0]
            item['zip'] = address_line.split(',')[-1].split()[1]
            item['street'] = address_line.split(',')[1].strip()
        except:
            item['location'] = ''
            item['city'] = ''
            item['state'] = ''
            item['zip'] = ''
            item['street'] = ''

        try:
            item['dateFrom'] = self.date_converter(response.xpath('//span[@class="date-display-single"]/text()').extract_first(default='').rstrip(' - '))
        except:
            try:
                item['dateFrom'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="date-display-single"]/text()').extract()[1].split('|')[0]
            except:
                item['dateFrom'] = ''
        try:
            item['startTime'] = self.time_converter(response.xpath('//span[@class="date-display-start"]/text()')[1].extract())
            # item['endTime'] = self.time_converter(response.xpath('//span[@class="date-display-end"]/text()')[1].extract())
        except:
            try:
                item['startTime'] = self.time_converter(response.xpath('//span[@class="date-display-single"]/text()').extract()[1].split(' | ')[1])
            except:
                item['startTime'] = ''
        item['In_group_id'] = ''
        try:
            item['ticketUrl'] = base_url + response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"btn-buy-tickets")]/@href').extract_first()
        except:
            item['ticketUrl'] = ''
        item['eventImage'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="views-field-field-speaker-photo-1"]/div/div/img/@src').extract_first(default='')
        item['organization'] = "New York Historical Society"

        yield item

    @staticmethod
    def date_converter(raw_date):
        try:
            raw_date_datetime_object = datetime.strptime(raw_date.replace(',',''), '%a %m/%d/%Y')
            final_date = raw_date_datetime_object.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            return final_date
        except:
            raw_date_datetime_object = datetime.strptime(raw_date.replace(',','').replace('th','').strip(), '%a %B %d %Y')
            final_date = raw_date_datetime_object.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            return final_date
    @staticmethod
    def time_converter(raw_time):
        raw_time_datetime_object = datetime.strptime(raw_time, '%I:%M %p')
        final_time = raw_time_datetime_object.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        return final_time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `CrawlSpider` the rules are as you mentioned for following the respective links **"until"** you find the ones that you actually want to get for an item.

But, how does the spider (or the rule) know when to stop? That is for the use of the `callback` and `follow` attributes. If you are using the `callback` then you don't need the `follow` (because `callback` specifies that that link needs to be handled as a response), and if you use the `follow` then you don't need the `callback`, because it tells the spider to continue on the quest for new links.

You'll have to define better rules and specify which ones to `follow` and which ones to return to a `callback`.

Comment: Thank you! In accordance with your suggestion, I modified my code like below and it works now!

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='.*?page=.*',restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="pager-next"]'), follow=True), Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="view-content"]/div[contains(@class,"views-row")]'), callback='parse_event_details'),]

Comment: So you have to use Rules, not possible without?

Comment: @JohnAndrews what do you mean? What are you trying to do? Rules are used with CrawlSpider

Comment: You have to use Rules in order to recursively scrape all the pages on a website? I used a simple example and noticed that also in my case it skips when it finds one use case. Thus I am looking for a concrete simple example how to expand this, that it doesn't stop when it finds one, but stops when found all urls